# How can you cascade filter the attributes of more dimensions in a SSAS cube, viewed in Excel 2007

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, cube, cascade-filtering

How can you **cascade** filter the attributes of more dimensions in a SSAS cube, viewed in Excel 2007.

For example, if we have a cube *Sales* with the dimension *Time* and dimension *Client*, once the dimension *Time* is filtered to show only the sales from a particular date, if "Client.ClientName" is chosen as a filter in the filter area, how can the list of clients be filtered so that only the clients that have sales in the particular date, be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [www.clicksoft.ro](http://www.clicksoft.ro)

The product named QuickCubeFiltrator is a wizard like addin for excel 2007 that does cascade filtering. Might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this before and haven't had much luck. Not sure you can really do it easily. You can try using named sets and calculated members but most of the time it depends on your data and hierarchies. You can also look at reporting services, and how it does it behind the scenes in MDX, but I don't know what good that will do you in Excel though. Like I said, this is a tough one.